# Insert new or update

Tags: customer, products, importexport

I must to export from another db and import into magento.
I must to insert or update products or customers.

I maked the import new products or customers. I can also update?

I have this code:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 

Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getDefaultAttributeSetId(); 

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); try{ $product ->setStoreId(1) ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) [...] ) ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); 

$product->save(); } 

catch(Exception $e)

{ Mage::log($e->getMessage()); }
```

this code add a new product. Correct? If i want update and not add a new product? –

Comment: Is it an existing Magento Database or a new Magento database?

Comment: Can you try and reword your question please? Perhaps add drawings or examples of what you want to do. Because 'as it' I have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: I have this code:

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
    try{
    $product 
    ->setStoreId(1) 
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
    [...]
    )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10));
    $product->save();  }
    catch(Exception $e){
    Mage::log($e->getMessage()); 
    }


this code add a new product. Correct?

If i want update and not add a new product?

Comment: Are you importing to a new Magento site or an existing Magento site? Why don't you use Dataflow?

Comment: I must to connect the magento database with a another software this another database. i must to extract customers, products, discount role one once a day.
If customer product is new i need to add, if the customer or product is modified into i need to update.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Magento API in the scenario you are describing. The API will accomplish all your tasks in Magento. You will need to call the API from your other application or you could develop a simple extension that "Pulls" info from your other system on a cron.

The API will allow you to make your operation work without having to worry about csv files or anything like that.